# How to append data in file at particular section of file only using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am bit new to python , i have a file where it contains data like :

```
##### Section 1 ######
[Mango]
Hello #value 1
```

i need to append data like :

```
####### Section 1 , Section 2 #######
[Mango]
Hello # value 1 , value 2
```

i'll be passing `section 2` , `value 2` and `key[Mango]` or any other key.
if `Key[Mango]` is already present in file then i need to append that section of file itself like output i've mentioned.
Not able to figure out to do in Python. Can you please help me here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that using python [configParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). Something like this:

```
parser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser() 
parser.read(<yourFileName>)
```

Then you can read each section:

```
parser.get(<sectionNAme>, <key>)
```

For example:

```
parser.get('Mango', 'Hello')
```

Or write:

```
parser.set('mango', 'Hello', <value>)
```